# Slow download speed when not using ExpressVPN; especially for overseas, especially for single-connection. Upload not affected

Tags: networking, vpn, speedtest

I have a confusing internet speed issue.

My setup

- I have ostensibly a 100 up / 20 down plan (FTTP on Aus NBN).
- I also sometimes use ExpressVPN
- I am also testing across my phone and my desktop for extra stats
- I am in Australia

My issue

- Download speeds can be very slow, especially overseas (e.g. HK and SG)
- This happens on both the desktop and the phone
- It does NOT seem to happen when Express VPN is turned on (connected to "Sydney")

I have done a table of download and upload speeds from both my phone and my desktop, both with and without Express VPN turned on, and for Sydney, HK and SG - see below.

I spend all day connecting to HK and SG via a company VPN (single connection?) that cannot be wrapped by ExpressVPN, so I am often experiencing the very worst of these connection speeds.

Any ideas what on earth is going on here?

[image]

Edit: DNS provider

[image]

Comment: What DNS provider are you using?

Comment: I have never configured the DNS provider myself - I have just now used this tool to get the DNS provider info edited into the question https://www.top10vpn.com/tools/what-is-my-dns-server/

Comment: This is unlikely to be a DNS issue.    I would do a few things to narrow it down - (1) Connect via a physical cable to rule out (admittedly unlikely) WIFI issues.   I'd also run something like WinMTR to look for packet loss and if it exists where it comes in.   That said, I do wonder if there is an MTU issue.   What happens if you reduce the MTU on your computer?   (If that fixes it, talk to your ISP about MTU settings on the router and MTU clamping)

Comment: (MTU is a tricky one to peg down - but its worth noting that VPN's very often do MTU clamping, which could be solving the problem when using a VPN. )

Comment: @tim654321 - Don’t use that tool. Manually change it to a different DNS provider other than the one provided by your ISP. I disagree that DNS isn’t involved since your issue is resolved by using a VPN

Comment: Changing to 4k or 9k for the MTU in the 'jumbo frame' setting did not make a difference (default was disabled).

Comment: Changing to cloudflare DNS per https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/setup/windows/ did not make a difference. Note I have IP v6 disabled by default and enabling it made some websites stop working.

Comment: I also tried turning on IPv6 on both the connection and the router, but that didn't make a difference either [previously turning on ipv6 for just the connection stopped some websites, but turning it on on the router has everything working, but still slow]

Comment: Also, fwiw, I had already updated my LAN driver from the motherboard manufacturer website before doing all the tests (Gigabyte B550m DS3H)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the answer was to change ISPs due my original ISP's international routing being a bit crap.

Tangerine Telecom, using the Vocus backend, was not good. I did spend a while with a ticket open, but they said they only guarantee speed to your nearest server and said they won't be able to help with overseas speed

- https://bgp.he.net/AS9443 (routing %s)
- https://bgp.tools/as/9443#connectivity (routing connectivity)

I am now with Launtel, which mostly uses GSL, and some Hurricane Elec, and I'm getting high speeds without the VPN

- https://bgp.he.net/AS134697 (routing %s)
- https://bgp.tools/as/134697#connectivity (routing connectivity)

This thread on Whirlpool was also a good start for helping choose Launtel. Superloop was my second/next choice if Launtel didn't work out.

- https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/35pn0knl